# Error in check_aesthetic when building a ShinyApp with the ggplot package

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, module

Recently I tried to make a module which is a small part of the Shiny App that I am building. However, I am receiving errors and I couldn't understand why, and I am hoping that an extra eye here could help me see through the error.

The error:

```
Warning: Error in check_aesthetics: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): y
  187: <Anonymous>
```

First, lets understand how the module work. It takes on a data frame with Date, Name, and TW, which corresponds to the date of the release of the product, the name of the product and TW, which is the price of the product. Using this data frame, I am supposed to plot a line chart with the x-axis as the date, price as the y-axis and group the dataset by Name (so three products means I have three line segments in my graph). See the MWE for the data frame here:

```
aggregated <- data.frame(Date = c("Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 3", "Day 3"), 
                         Name = c("Product A", "Product B", "Product C", "Product A", "Product B", "Product C", "Product A", "Product B", "Product C"), 
                         TW = c(84, 969, 6800, 84, 969, 6800, 84, 888, 6720))
```

And here is a MWE of my module's UI:

```
graph_UI <- function(id) {
  fluidRow(
    plotOutput(NS(id, "plot"), hover = NS(id, "plot_hover"))
  )
}
```

Alongside the MWE of my module's server side:

```
graph_Server <- function(id, values) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Create (or import) the data frame 
    aggregated <- data.frame(Date = c("Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 3", "Day 3"), 
                             Name = c("Product A", "Product B", "Product C", "Product A", "Product B", "Product C", "Product A", "Product B", "Product C"), 
                             TW = c(84, 969, 6800, 84, 969, 6800, 84, 888, 6720))
                            
    # Plot plot_one which is Price (I called it TW here) against Date, grouped by Name
    plot_one <- ggplot(aggregated, aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(Date)), y = TW, fill = Name)) +
      geom_line()
    
    # Render the plot
    output$plot <- renderPlot({plot_one})
    
    # Add a label when user hover on the plot
    observeEvent(input$plot_hover, {
      if (!is.null(input$plot_hover$x)) {
        x <- round(input$plot_hover$x, 0) # extract the x coordinate and round it
        
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
          plot_one + 
            geom_vline(xintercept = x, linetype = "longdash") + # if user hover, add a horizontal line to the nearest x closest to the hover's x-coordinate 
            geom_label(x = x + (0.01 * length(unique(aggregated$Date))), y = round(as.numeric(input$plot_hover$y), 0), label = "Some words here") 
           # similarly add a geom_label slightly to the right of the `x` point and at the `y` point by specifying my x and y in geom_label()
        })
      }
    })
  })
}
```

The server side is slightly complicated. But the whole idea is to create the `aggregated` data frame and plot a `plot_one` using the data frame. And if there is any hover, the app will add a `geom_vline` at the hover point, and add a label at my desired x and y coordinates.

Finally, to test the module:

```
# Test the app
graph_App <- function() {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    graph_UI("graph")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    graph_Server("graph")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
}

graph_App()
```

Looks like the error is saying that the `y` argument I provided in `geom_label()` is not length 1 or the same length as my data. But shouldn't `round(as.numeric(input$plot_hover$y), 0)` be a single value, as `input$plot_hover$y` is a single value? When I render the value of `input$plot_hover$y` to check it still provides me with a single value.

What went wrong here for R to throw this error? The plot output is perfect, but as soon as I hover to a single point on the plot, my app crashed and threw the warning to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `output$plot` twice; IDs should be unique. Also, no need to nest the `renderPlot` inside the `observer`.  Try this

```
graph_Server <- function(id, values) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    plot_on <- reactiveValues(e=NULL)
    # Create (or import) the data frame 
    aggregated <- data.frame(Date = c("Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 3", "Day 3", "Day 3"), 
                             Name = c("Product A", "Product B", "Product C", "Product A", "Product B", "Product C", "Product A", "Product B", "Product C"), 
                             TW = c(84, 969, 6800, 84, 969, 6800, 84, 888, 6720))
    
    # Plot plot_one which is Price (I called it TW here) against Date, grouped by Name
    plot_on$e <- ggplot(aggregated, aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(Date)), y = TW, fill = Name)) +
      geom_line()
    
    # Render the plot
    output$plot <- renderPlot({plot_on$e})
    
    # Add a label when user hover on the plot
    observeEvent(input$plot_hover, {
      if (!is.null(input$plot_hover$x)) {
        x <- round(input$plot_hover$x, 0) # extract the x coordinate and round it
        
        #output$plot <- renderPlot({
          plot_on$e <- plot_on$e + 
            geom_vline(xintercept = x, linetype = "longdash") + # if user hover, add a horizontal line to the nearest x closest to the hover's x-coordinate 
            geom_label(x = x + (0.01 * length(unique(aggregated$Date))), y = round(as.numeric(input$plot_hover$y), 0), label = "Some words here") 
          # similarly add a geom_label slightly to the right of the `x` point and at the `y` point by specifying my x and y in geom_label()
        #})
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: It almost worked. However, when I hover on a second point, the `plot_on$e` will still have the first label from the first hover point. I think perhaps it is better to assign `plot_on$e`  that has the `geom_label` in another reactive value. Or is there a better workaround for this issue?

Comment: It will lead to flashing point display.  I was not aware of this new requirement.

Comment: I think not having multiple `geom_label` every time I hover on a new point would make sense. Either way, your answer solved the issue I have on hand. I assume the `input$plot_hover` values got messed up because of me calling `output$plot` twice. Is that it?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.